# How to create SQL Agent job to automatically restore a database from latest backups?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, jobs

There are 3 different folders which store respectively full, differential, and log backups. Different types of backups occur in different schedules. Now I need to create a new job which will periodically restore the database in order to assure the consistency of the backups. There are some third party tools available but I do not want to use them. Now, I can't figure out how to specify in the Job Step script to choose the **last** full/dif/log backups from their folders? The thing is there are multiple files already in the folders.

Comment: This could help.. https://docs.dbatools.io/#Test-DbaLastBackup

Comment: Do you use Ola's backup solution for taking backups ?

Comment: no actually @Kin but I'll look up what is it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to the problem is described: 
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1584/auto-generate-sql-server-restore-script-from-backup-files-in-a-directory/